# Searching function starting exactly constant and approaching another constant

Tags: functions

for the default of an R API parameter i seek a function that has the property of yielding a good guess.

- I want the function to be defined for $\mathbb Z^+$ (But no reason not to define it for $\mathbb R^+$, i guess)
- I want it to be smooth
- It should satisfy both

  $$\mathrm f(x_{small}) = 1 \forall x_{small} \in \left(0, k\right]$$
  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm f(x) = l$$

edit to be clear: $k$ and $l$ should be constants appearing in the function definition.

E.g. with $k = 1000$ and $l = 0$, the $f(x) = 1 \forall x \in (0, 1000]$. Then it should gradually decline and approach 0.

To simplify, the function can be written as:

$$
\mathrm f(x) = \begin{cases}
1     & \text{if } x \le k \\
[\dots] & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Maybe y=1? Then $l=1$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\forall x, f(x)=f(x_{small})=1$

Comment: well, I want $k$ and $l$ constants that appear in the definition. apologies if that wasn’t clear

Comment: A  solution of a differential equation permissible ?

Comment: you mean it has to be solved numerically? i’m sure that’s not necessary. if necessary, one could use a branching like $\mathrm f(x) = 1 \text{ if }x \le k\text{, else } \dots$

Comment: If you only define it on $ZZ^+$ then it does not make sense to ask for smoothness.

Comment: sure, this is why i mentioned $\mathbb R^+$. what i meant is mostly $\mathrm f^\prime(k) = 0$

Answer (score -2):

One example is:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}+1}$$

Comment: no. there is no plateau at the beginning. and where are `k` and `l`?